# How create XLSX file from LibXML::XML::Document in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xlsx, libxml2

My code prepares a string containing XML data in UTF-8 encoding. I use LibXML to create it and finally I call Rails send_data which creates some.xls file from the prepared string. MS Excel perfectly opens the some.xls file, but it's the only application which can open an XML file in table format.

Does anybody know how to create an XLSX file from `LibXML::XML::Document`? I need to create a spreadsheet at once,not cell by cell.

I checked some gems like `XlsxWriter`,etc. However, I found the only examples use methods writing into a cell or a row o a column, but I need to create a file at once.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look the `axlsx` gem, I think this will help you.

https://github.com/randym/axlsx

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion. I checked axlsx, but it also uses methods like sheet.add_row(). 

Maybe I was not so clear. I have LibXML::XML::Document. How I can get xlsx from it?  I don't thing doc.to_xlsx will work because it's designed for ActiveRecord based classes.

Comment: Seems nobody knows the answer. I searched Internet with no results as well.

Comment: Hey, I think there is no method that will solve your problem. I Would suggest following scenario: First you need to extract your values from `LibXML::XML::Document` than you can export it to `xlsx` through this gem.